# CODA - Удобный файловый менеджер как в OS Mac для Windows

Tags: windows, mac, ос

Суть вопроса, есть в маке прога под названием CODA, это ftp менеджер со своим встроенным редактором, очень удобная програмка, яб ради только одной ее перешел на мак, но хочу поиграть игры. Так вот есть ли аналог такой программы для Window?

Comment: Материть? Это невежливо. У нас принято подобные вопросы закрывать, как склонные к образованию жарких бессмысленных дискуссий. Кстати, а почему Linux не рассматриваете?

Comment: @Кнопкатык, на Linux кажется нет программного обеспечения от adobe или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Ну... *формально* ошибаетесь, есть как минимум Brackets. Но кроме него, вроде, ничего. В вопросе вы, кстати, совершенно не указали, что им пользуетесь. Поэтому такие вопросы и закрывают, нужды у всех разные, поэтому любые ответы на такие вопросы скорее вводят в заблуждение, чем помогают.

Comment: Brackets весьма таки глючный, по крайне мере пишу на Node и часто сталкиваюсь с его глюками, надо таки собраться и перейти на Sublime

Comment: @vnn198 на мой вкус Brackets очень узконаправленный. Предпочитаю Sublime и Atom. Первый пошустрее, второй поумнее.

Comment: `заходит на сервера что-то там редактировать, копировать удалять и так далее` - а я использую программку ssh.

Comment: @Кнопкатык, в смисле ssh, я на виндовсе пользуюсь прогой PuTyy соеденяюсь только для управление сервером, например передергнуть его. А когда делаю сайт или правлю код то удобнее работать с ftp менеджером

Comment: В Linux есть нормальный клиент SSH безо всяких PuTTY. А от правок по FTP отучайтесь. Вносите изменения на локальной копии и выкатывайте сразу пачкой, зная, что ничего не сломается.

Comment: К сожалению, вы заменили один оффтопик на другой, не меньший оффтопик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хоть заминусуют но отвечу, я наверное всё-таки за Mac, объясню почему, в принципе Mac это по сути UNIX (точнее FreeBSD) , в красивой и удобной обёртке, то есть например навыки с работой в консоле очень помогают потом при работе с серверами под linux, иногда у меня бывает под виндой как наберёшь ls и думаешь что за хрень, очень удобно что сохраняются все открытые окна при выключении, под виндой очень нехватает. А что касается сборки , можно купить б/у на авито, Mac PRO 4.1/5.1 можно взять за 60т.р. , я покупал подобный , хотя надо сидеть и мониторить , он хоть был и с одним процессором , но зато 32Гб памяти , 250SSD + 3HDD в сумме на 6Tb. в принципе за глаза хватит даже macmini с SSD если не увлекатся виртуалками